# How to make devices connected through ethernet sharing port be able to see devices on the Wifi Network

Tags: network, wifi, ethernet, internet-sharing

My home network is 192.168.1.0.
I am sharing my wifi connection through my MBP Mid 2010 ethernet port.
So my MBP is also on 192.168.2.0 as well as the device that is plugged on the this internet port.
How to make the connected device visible on my home network and make the home network visible to this device?
In my shallow knowledge I got to route the traffic from one network to the other and vice versa, but how?? I am running Maverick BTW.

Comment: what do you mean by "visible" to whom, where ?

Comment: in this particular case I got webserver on the network 192.168.1.0 that I would like to my arduino on 192.168.2.0 perform a GET request. I also got a socket on the arduino that I would like to make accessible for all device on wi-fi.

Comment: Hi, you are new here, if you are addressing someone specific use the @Buscar so i will get notified.